# Page not loading when refresh from browser in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, wordpress

I have used angularjs `htmlMode5` for routing like

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: true }).hashPrefix('!');
```

and in head section i have placed

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

And problem is angular $http request is not calling when i refresh page from browser.

Let me explain this in details :

I have used angularjs in wordpress for some of pages and when i navigate from one category pages to other category pages(Which is using angularjs for loading page), it is calling $http request and angular template and data is loading perfectly.

But when i refresh that perticular page from browser refresh button then it's loading nothing and nothing will display in output section.

If you click on this Angular Category one by one then its calling $http request and data is loading.

[image]

But when i click on browse refresh button then its not working.

[image]

My website is : http://templatic.net/test/
URL not working is : http://templatic.net/test/job_category/seo (Directly its not working)

Comment: I think to get rid off from this issue, you need to use <base> tag in your index.html

Comment: @ManishSingh Yes i have added *base* tag in head like *<base href="/test/index.php">*

Comment: Okay that's why it is not working. Use <base href="/test/"> only

Comment: Not working still i have tried it..plz chk it http://templatic.net/test/job_category/seo/

Comment: Please try removing <meta name="fragment" content="!"> because now it's deprecated.

Comment: opps..not working still...

Comment: Really, very strange! :(

Answer (score 1):

Check your index page , that you have base url tag like

```
<base href="/">
```

If it is not there , add this in your index page .

And have below changes in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /ProjectName

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

Where in above code 'ProjectName' is the name of your project